# Have chrome extension display on certain page using page action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension for the Pinterest.

I followed the examples I found from the Chrome extension [sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_url.zip) (the one with displaying icon in the omnibox when there is a 'g' in the url) and changed the file a bit to make it display the icon when the site has "pinterest.com" in it. Here is the code:

**manifest.json:**

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://*.pinterest.com/"
]
```

**background.js**, I copied most of the code from the example online:

```
function showPinterestAction(tabId, ChangeInfo, tab) {
  if(tab.url.indexOf('pinterest.com') > -1){
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  }
  /* This doesn't work. tab.url return undefine to me :( */
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, change, tab) {
  if (change.status == "complete") {
    showPinterestAction(tabId);
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tabId, info) {
  selectedId = tabId;
  showPinterestAction(tabId);
});

// Ensure the current selected tab is set up.
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  alert(tabs[0].id);
  showPinterestAction(tabs[0].id);
});
```

It is not displaying the icon at the right page. If I try to `alert(tab.url)` it gives me `undefined`. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't immediately see problems here.. Try using `"*://*.pinterest.com/*"` match pattern instead.

Comment: Also, see [`declarativeContent` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) for a much better approach; I'll try to add an example when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're only ever calling `showPinterestAction` with one parameter, `tabId`.

No surprises, therefore, that `tab` parameter is simply undefined. The signature of `showPinterestAction` follows the [tab update callback](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated), but you're not using it like one.

You can modify `showPinterestAction` to [pull the data](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-get) it needs:

```
function showPinterestAction(tabId) {
  chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab){
    if(tab.url.indexOf('pinterest.com') > -1){
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
  });
};
```

You also probably want to make your match pattern more general: `"*://*.pinterest.com/*"` should cover your use case.

---

Alternatively, instead of latching on to multiple `tabs` events, you can use [`declarativeContent` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) - it was created for this.

```
var rule = {
  conditions: [
    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      pageUrl: { hostSuffix: 'pinterest.com' }
    })
  ],
  actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule]);
  });
});
```

In this case you will not need "heavy" permissions like `"tabs"` or host permissions. Your manifest only needs

```
"permissions": [
   "declarativeContent", 
   "activeTab"
]
```

for this to work.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much :DDDD Is there any references other than the Chrome extension API guide that I can look up to make an extension :o

Comment: Be sure to read the [Overview page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), and not use so much smileys next time you ask a question here.